# Reaching controller scope on $rootScope.$on inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I reach the $scope and modify it from inside my $rootScope.$on event handler?

```
angular.module('Foo')
        .controller('BarCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
            $scope.x = {};
            $rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
                if(data){
                    //how to reach BarCtrl $scope.x here?
                }else{
                    //same here
                }
            })
        }])
```

Comment: You would do  `$scope.x = 'new value'` within the if statement.

Comment: what did you try that caused problems? There is nothing tricky here. Normal javascript scoping applies and `$scope.x` is accessible inside the event callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `$scope` variable

```
$rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
    $scope.x = data;
});
```

Comment: thanks! I must be doing something else that makes my view fail to update.